# Python code not writing in the hosts file

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am trying to write some content in the hosts file located at address = "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts", using the python code, but whenever I run the code, it gets executed with no error but doesn't write in the hosts file. I have given the administration privilege too. I am not able to understand what is wrong with my code. I am using the print statement just to be sure the code is working.

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import time
host_url = r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"
website_list = ["www.facebook.com","facebook.com","www.instagram.com","instagram.com"]

while True:
    if dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,8) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,16):
        print("Working hours...")
        with open(host_url,'r+') as file:
            content = file.read()
            for website in website_list:
                if website in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    file.write(redirect+" "+website+"\n")
    else:
        with open(host_url,'r+') as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            file.seek(0)
            for line in content:
                if not any(website in line for website in website_list):
                    file.write(line)
                file.truncate()
            print("Fun hours...")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

It`s a permission problem.

Run this script in your `cmd` with administrator permission (right click on cmd and press run as administrator), [info](https://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=16850)

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt 
hosts_location=r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
hosts_temp="hosts"
blocked_websites=['www.facebook.com','facebook.com']
redirect="127.0.0.1"

while True:
   if dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,8) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,17):
    with open(hosts_location,"r+") as file:
        content=file.read()
        for website in blocked_websites:
            if website in content:
                pass
            else:
                file.write(redirect+"\t"+website+"\n")
    print("Working Hours....")
else:
    with open(hosts_location,"r+") as file:
        content=file.readlines()
        file.seek(0)
        for line in content:
            if not any(website in line for website in blocked_websites):
                file.write(line)
        file.truncate()
    print("Fun Time...")
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Not working , tried

Comment: did you try run your script with admin rights? @MusaibGojwari

Comment: yes I did, but no effect